# Font size for enterprise applications

Tags: web-app, desktop-application, business-application, enterprise, font-sizes

Are there rules about what standard font size to use for enterprise applications? While websites use 16 pixels as the most readable for the user, many desktop applications use 12 to 14 pixels. What determines the choice of font size?

Comment: I think it really depends on the content and how much you want it to stand out. I mean, look at this webpage right now, there are numerous different font sizes (and styles) in play. Perhaps it would help your question if you could be more specific about the use case.

Comment: For example, Power bi or Tableau have small font size 12px or 14px, anyway but not 16px. But Evernote, Trello have bigger font - it might be even 16px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enterprise applications tend to have a longer history and therefore inherit legacy design or code as the product evolves. Not only that, the nature of enterprise applications moving from a desktop based software to cloud-based offerings has also influenced its design and made it similar to website and webpages in some respects (e.g. font size).

I think it is still too difficult to say what the accepted font size for enterprise applications is, but there is an overall trend of increasing font size to improve accessibility and readability.

The type of application and therefore the nature of the content (e.g. section headings and body text size) and interactions involved (e.g. button labels and input field font sizes) is still probably the most common way in which applications are designed and the increase in monitor sizes and resolution of the screen also accounts for some of the changes that we are seeing at the moment.